# Use of this Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

New to JS.. can anyone tell me if the use of this is appropriate in the below function:

```
var Vector = (function()...

this.prototype.add = function(someVector2){

    var tmpVect = this;
    tmpVector.x += someVector2.x;
    tmpVector.y += someVector2.y;
    return tmpVect;
};
```

In the sense that 'var tmpVect = this' will result in a local Vector variable with the x & y attributes of the vector that called the function?

Cheers

Comment: You can assign `x` and `y` to `this`, so I don't see why you need another reference to it.

Comment: `var tmpVect = this` does not create a new Vector. It just creates another **reference** to the same one.

Comment: Yeah that's cool, I don't want the addition to change the vector calling it, just to return a vector with the result.

Comment: @Fendorio the way it's written now, it **will** change the vector. If you don't want to do that, you'd need to have the "add" code create a new Vector and initialize its "x" and "y" properties to be the sum of the properties from the original two vectors.

Comment: Instead of `this.prototype.add`, you probably want to create `Vector.prototype.add`

Comment: Ohh ok that's cool. I was reading up on reference/value in JS made me change the tmpVect from = new Vector... to this. Cheers for clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite this like so:(based on your comments)

```
var Vector = function(){

}

Vector.prototype.add = function(someVector2){
    var tmpVector = new Vector;
    tmpVector.x =  this.x + someVector2.x;
    tmpVector.y = this.y + someVector2.y;

    return tmpVector;
}
```

Then you could invoke it like so:

```
var someVector = new Vector();
var addedVector = someVector.add(someVector);
```

The above would store a new Vector in `addedVector` that would have an `x` and `y` value double that of `someVector`.

Comment: That is a good answer to my original question. Although in your add function would it not be best to return new Vector(this.x + ..., this.y+ ...)? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

New objects are only declared in very explicit ways; "new Vector()", or "variable = {x:5, y:2}", etc. Whenever you write "something = somethingElse", no *new* objects are going to be created. You can even confirm this using the *triple-equals* comparator.

```
v1 = new Vector(1, 2);
v2 = new Vector(1, 2);
v1 === v2 // will return false

v3 = v1;
v1 === v3 // will return true

v1.x = 17;
v3.x // will return 17
```

For ease of development, you might define a Vector prototype function "clone", that creates and returns a "`new Vector()`" with the same x and y as the original. If you want a new one for `add()`'s return, you'll need to do something like that.

Also: ryan's answer is tangentially correct - you should only define prototype functions once, not every time a Vector is created.

Comment: I disagree that objects are created explicitly. Most notorious is `function(){}` which always creates a rather heavy object yet people do it even in loops or functions when it can be done just once per program

Comment: Well, I didn't quite think to include the disclaimers - but my answer is mostly focused on terms of understanding the functional programming of objects and how to design your program; not understanding memory management and performance considerations. Usually, someone could get by making huge complex programs without knowing that factoid about functions being recreated; they might just have some work to do when they profile it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I would write it. It also has a trick I read about from David Herman for making your constructors `new` agnostic. This means you don't necessarily have to make a new `Vector` with the `new` keyword.

```
function Vector(x,y) {
  // Make the constructor `new` agnostic
  if (!(this instanceof Vector)) {
    return new Vector(x,y);
  }

  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  return this;
}

Vector.prototype.add = function(someVector2) {
  this.x += someVector2.x;
  this.y += someVector2.y;

  return this;
};

// Example
var myVector = new Vector(1,2);
var myOtherVector = Vector(1,2);

myVector.add(myOtherVector);
```

Comment: It comes with significant performance penalty http://jsperf.com/123412314 . If you have trouble using `new` use strict mode and jshint.